# How calculate period for a discontinuous system using fix point iteration?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, periodic-functions

I have dynamic system that performs a periodic motion. It is a woodpecker hammering down a rod and its motion is described by two states depending if some constraints are activated or not. These states are

**State I** :

$$(I_2+m_2b^2)\ddot{\theta}=-c\theta+m_2bg_{gr}\tag{1}$$

**State II** :

$$(I_2+m_2b^2(1-\frac{m_2}{m_1+m_2}))\ddot{\theta}=-c\theta\tag{2}$$
$$(m_1+m_2)\ddot{z}+m_2b\ddot{\theta}=(m_1+m_2)g_{gr}\tag{3}$$

Now, when I simulate this in Matlab I get (after the transient part dies out) a periodic solution (this is indicated by the phaseplot below).

[image]

But how do I calculate its period? I dont want to measure the period graphically, instead I want to use fixpoint iteration. But the system is discontinuous and all that, so it seems really complicated. However, my professor gave me this advice:

The system is decribed by an explicit ODE

$$\dot{y}=f(y)$$ where $$y=(\theta, \dot{\theta},z,\dot{z})^T$$ is the statevector.

We wish to calculate the period $T$:

$$y(t;y_0),\quad y(0;y_0)=y_0,\quad y(T;y_0)=y_0$$

We define the function $F$ as:

$$F(y_0)\equiv y(T;y_0)-y_0 \iff F(y_0)=0$$

which is a nonlinear system of equations. Now, since we don't know T, which is what we wish to find out, we cannot solve it. His approach was to make the following transformation

$$t\in[0,T]\mapsto s\in[0,1],\quad s=\frac{t}{T}$$

Then we can present nonlinear system of equations in a different form

$$\frac{dy}{ds}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}=Tf(y),\quad s\in [0,1]$$

$$\bar{y}\equiv (y,T)^T \Rightarrow \frac{d\bar{y}}{ds}=(Tf(y),0)^T=g(\bar{y})$$

Finally we arrive at a nonlinear system of equations independent of $T$

$$G(y_0)=\bar{y}(1;\bar{y}_0)-\bar{y}_0 \iff G(y_0)=0$$

I am not quite sure why we need to differentiate $\bar{y}$. My quesetion is how I implement this method numerically? I dont'quite understand how fix point iteration works in this case. Do I guess a initial value $\bar{y_0}$ and then $\bar{y}(1;\bar{y}_0)-\bar{y}_0$ becomes the new guess that I insert which brings me closer to the fixed point. Then I do a backtransformation to obtain the period $T$ using the expression $T=t/s$. In that case, what is $t$?

I hope I am being coherent in my questions. Best regards

Edit: Regarding the last question what $t$ is, this is ofcourse the period since $s$ is 1.

Edit 2:

So, for my system to complete one cycle/period it goes through different stages, and every stage yields a new set of equations to be solved. So if I treat this as a boundary value problem, the trouble becomes that the integration process must be terminated and started several timed during the procedure. Can a BVP solver handle this?

The cycle goes like this:

*Stage* 1: Solve **State I** for arbitrary intialvalue $y_0$.

*Stage* 2: Solve **Sate II** for initialvalue $y_1$.

*Stage* 3: Solve **State I** for initialvalue $y_2$.

*Stage* 4: Solve **State I** for initial value $y_3$.

*Stage* 5: Solve **State II** for initial value $y_4$.

When Stage 5 terminates, then the cycle is *complete*.

So how do I implement the idea of this being a boundaary value problem when it is discontinous like this?

Edit 3:

CODE

```
%General constants
I2 = 7*10^(-7); % [kgm^2]
m1 = 0.003; % [kg]
m2 = 0.0045; % [kg]
b = 0.015; % [m]
c = 0.0056; % [Nm]
d1 = 0.18335;
d3 = 0.04766;
g = 9.81; % [m/s^2]
K1 = 0.174532925; % [rads]
K2 = 0.20943951; % [rads]
p = [I2 m1 m2 b c d1 d3 g K1 K2]; % parametervector

% Constants to the function firstODE
A1 =  I2 + m2*b^2;
B1 = m2*b*g;

% Constants to the function secondODE
A2 = I2 + m2*b^2*(1-m2/(m1+m2));
B2 = m1 + m2;
C2 = m2*b;
D2 = (m1 + m2)*g;

IC = [K1+0.01 15.2161 0 0]; % Initial Condition

tstart = 0;
tfinal = 10;

y0 = IC;
options = odeset('Events',@myEventsFcn);
tout = tstart;

% Lists for different statevariables output
thout = y0(1:1);
thvout = y0(2:2);
zout = y0(3:3);
zvout = y0(4:4);

ieout = [];
yeout = [];
if isempty(ieout)
    if y0(1)>K1
        ieout = [ieout 5];
    elseif  K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 1];
    elseif -K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)<0
        ieout = [ieout 2];
    elseif -K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K2 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 3];
    elseif K1>y0(1) && y0(1)>-K1 && y0(2)>0
        ieout = [ieout 4];
    end
end

% Main program
for i = 1:25 % Change this to 5 for one cycle (sometimes 4 will do, as long as it is one period)
    event = ieout(end);
    switch event
        case 1
            [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode45(@(t,y) secondODE(t,y,A2,B2,C2,D2,c),[0 tfinal],y0,options);
            [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout]=Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,2);
            ie = ie(end);
            ieout = [ieout ie];
            ye=ye(end,:);
            y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p);
        case 2
            y00 = [y0(1) y0(2)];
            [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode45(@(t,y) firstODE(t,y,A1,B1,c),[0 tfinal],y00,options);
            [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout]=Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,1);
            ie = ie(end);
            ieout = [ieout ie];
            ye = [ye(end,:) zout(end) zvout(end)];
            y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p);
        case 3
            y00 = [y0(1) y0(2)];
            [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode45(@(t,y) firstODE(t,y,A1,B1,c),[0 tfinal],y00,options);
            [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout]=Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,1);
            ie = ie(end);
            ieout = [ieout ie];
            ye = [ye(end,:) zout(end) zvout(end)];
            y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p);
        case 4
            [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode45(@(t,y) secondODE(t,y,A2,B2,C2,D2,c),[0 tfinal],y0,options);
            [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout]=Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,2);
            ie = ie(end);
            ieout = [ieout ie];
            ye = ye(end,:);
            y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p);
        case 5
            y00 = [y0(1) y0(2)];
            [t,y,te,ye,ie] = ode45(@(t,y) firstODE(t,y,A1,B1,c),[0 tfinal],y00,options);
            [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout]=Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,1);
            ie = ie(end);
            ieout = [ieout ie];
            ye = [ye(end,:) zout(end) zvout(end)];
            y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p);
    end
end

k1 = repmat(K1,1,length(tout));
k2 = repmat(-K2,1,length(tout));

% This section gives different plots. Remember to comment out what you
% don't want to plot!

plot(tout,thout)
hold on
plot(tout,k1)
hold on
plot(tout,-k1)
hold on
plot(tout,k2)

legend('\theta(t)','K1','-K1','-K2')
title('Vinkelutslag kontra tid')
xlabel('tid')
ylabel('vinkel')

% plot(tout,thvout)
% legend('d\theta/dt')
% title('Vinkelhastighet kontra tid')
% xlabel('tid')
% ylabel('vinkelhastighet')

% plot(thout,thvout)
% legend('Faskurva')
% title('Fasporträtt med B.V. (0.175532925, 15.2161, 0, 0)')
% xlabel('\theta')
% ylabel('d\theta/dt')

% plot(tout,zout)
% legend('z(t)','Location','northwest')
% title('Position i z-led kontra tid')
% xlabel('tid')
% ylabel('z-koordinat')

% plot(tout,zvout)
% legend('dz/dt(t)','Location','northwest')
% title('Fallhastighet kontra tid')
% xlabel('tid')
% ylabel('hastighet i z-led')

% plot(thout,thvelout) % lägg till y0 då i=5 för fullständig plott
% thout = [thout y0(1)]; % y0(1)
% thvelout = [thvelout y0(2)]; % y0(2)
% plot(thout, thvelout)

function [thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout] =     Update(y,t,thout,thvout,zout,zvout,tstart,tout,i)

    % This function updates the variables in a correct way since the
    % degrees of freedom change, thus some variables are constant or zero.
      nt = length(t);
      t_new = t(2:nt)' + tstart;
      tout = [tout t_new];
      tstart = tstart + t(end);

      thout = [thout y(2:nt,1)']; 
      thvout = [thvout y(2:nt,2)'];

      if i == 1 %first ODE
          zstat = repmat(zout(end),1,nt-1);
          zout = [zout zstat];
          zvstat = zeros(nt-1,1);
          zvout = [zvout zvstat'];

      elseif i == 2 %second ODE
          zout = [zout y(2:nt,3)'];
          zvout = [zvout y(2:nt,4)'];

      end
end

function dy = firstODE(t,y,A1,B1,c)
dy = zeros(2,1);
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = 1/(A1)*(B1-c*y(1));
end


function dy = secondODE(t,y,A2,B2,C2,D2,c)
dy = zeros(4,1); 
dy(1) = y(2);
dy(2) = -c/A2*y(1);
dy(3) = y(4);
dy(4) = D2/B2 + c*C2/(A2*B2)*y(1);
end

function [value,isterminal,direction] = myEventsFcn(t,y)
K1 = 0.174532925; % 0.174532925 rads
K2 = 0.20943951; % 0.20943951 rads
value = [y(1)-K1, y(1)+K1, y(1)+K2, y(1)+K1, y(1)-K1];
isterminal = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
direction = [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1];
end

function y0 = ICgenerate(ye,ie,p)
% Generates new Initial Conditions based on which event happend

thetapos = ye(1);
thetavel  = ye(2);
zetapos = ye(3);
zetavel = ye(4);
if ie == 1
    tpos = thetapos;
    tvel = thetavel;
    zpos = zetapos;
    zvel = 0;
    y0 = [tpos tvel zpos zvel];
end
if ie == 2
    tpos = thetapos;
    tvel = (1-p(7))*(thetavel+p(3)*p(4)/(p(1)+p(3)*p(4)^2)*zetavel);
    zpos = zetapos;
    zvel = 0;
    y0 = [tpos tvel zpos zvel];
end
if ie == 3
    tpos = thetapos;
    tvel = -thetavel;
    zpos = zetapos;
    zvel = 0;
    y0 = [tpos tvel zpos zvel];
end
if ie == 4
    tpos = thetapos;
    tvel = thetavel;
    zpos = zetapos;
    zvel = 0;
    y0 = [tpos tvel zpos zvel];
end
if ie == 5
    tpos = thetapos;
    tvel = (1-p(6))*(thetavel+p(3)*p(4)/(p(1)+p(3)*p(4)^2)*zetavel);
    zpos = zetapos;
    zvel = 0;
    y0 = [tpos tvel zpos zvel];
end   
end
```

Comment: Do you have to implement the fixed-point method yourself or can you use some standard BVP solver? The transformation is mostly helpful for the latter case. I used an implementation following the given method, but not using the full functionality of the BVP solver, in https://stackoverflow.com/q/42936333/3088138

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That I had not thought of, BVP solver would work fine for this type of problem. I'll check it out.

Comment: @LutzL So I checked out your previous approach,and I think it might work with some modifications to it. Please check out my second edit to my original post. Do you still think it is possible to use that approach you recommended? I am confused how to solve such a boundary value problem

Comment: It would help if you could give more detail on how exactly to produce your plot and the solutions contained therein. What are the stages relative to the plot (the smooth sections?), what is the integration interval in each stage? Also, is the equation for $z$ the same for both states? Has $z$ any influence on $y$?

Comment: @LutzL Yes that I can do. Right now I am in my phone, the minute I get on the computer I will provide you with all the plots, equations and code (in Matlab). I can tell you this right away, the integration interval depends on a so called event function, i.e. a geometric/algebraic contstraint. When the state is such that the constraint equals zero, then the integration terminates.

Comment: @LutzL My statevariables are \theta and z and their derivatives. z has no influence on \theta, but \theta has influence on z. You can elimnate the second derivative of \theta in the second system of equations I wrote in the beggining of my post, then you will see that this is true. I have now added my code, so you can just copy it into matlab and plot the figures.